# Loading data from multiple CSV into MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql-server, database, stock-data

I am trying to load multiple csv files into mysql to create a single table of those multiple files. I've a table named symbols loaded in mysql which has one column named as ticker and all the row values represent symbols like A, B, C etc. I would want to loop over these rows to create a path as `/path/A.csv` so that I can read data from all these files to create new table all_tickers.

Earlier I did this in SQL Server using the following code:

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.all_tickers
(
     ticker_symbol varchar(32) NOT NULL,
     [Date] datetime2(7) NOT NULL,
     [Open] float NULL,
     High float NULL,
     Low float NULL,
     [close] float NULL,
     Volume float NULL,

     PRIMARY KEY (ticker_symbol, [Date])
);
GO

DECLARE @Path nvarchar(255) = 'D:\ASX';
DECLARE @SQL nvarchar(MAX);

CREATE TABLE #ticker_staging
(
     [Date] datetime2(7) NOT NULL,
     [Open] float NULL,
     High float NULL,
     Low float NULL,
     [close] float NULL,
     Volume float NULL
);

SET @SQL = (SELECT N'
TRUNCATE TABLE #ticker_staging;
BULK INSERT #ticker_staging
    FROM ''' + @Path + N'\' + ticker + N'.csv''
    WITH
    (
    FIRSTROW = 2,
    FIELDTERMINATOR = '','',  --CSV field delimiter
    ROWTERMINATOR = ''\n'',   --Use to shift the control to next row
    TABLOCK
    );
INSERT INTO dbo.all_tickers WITH (TABLOCKX)(
  ticker_symbol,
  [Date],
  [Open],
  High,
  Low,
  [close],
  Volume
) 
SELECT
  ''' + ticker + N''',
  [Date],
  [Open],
  High,
  Low,
  [close],
  Volume
FROM #ticker_staging;'
FROM dbo.symbols
FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value('.',N'nvarchar(MAX)');
EXECUTE sp_executesql @SQL;
GO
```

To replicate the results in MySQL I've changed the above code so for to as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.all_tickers
(
     ticker_symbol varchar(32) NOT NULL,
     Date datetime NOT NULL,
     Open float NULL,
     High float NULL,
     Low float NULL,
     close float NULL,
     Volume float NULL,

     PRIMARY KEY (ticker_symbol, Date)
);

set @Path = 'D:\ASX';
set @SQL = nvarchar(MAX);

CREATE TABLE #ticker_staging 
( 
    Date1 datetime NOT NULL,
    Open float NULL,
    High float NULL,
    Low float NULL,
    close float NULL,
    Volume float NULL
);

SET @SQL = (SELECT N'
TRUNCATE TABLE #ticker_staging;
LOAD DATA INFILE #ticker_staging
    FROM ''' + @Path + N'\' + ticker + N'.csv''
    WITH
    (
    FIRSTROW = 2,
    FIELDTERMINATOR = '','',  #CSV field delimiter
    ROWTERMINATOR = ''\n'',   #Use to shift the control to next row
    TABLOCK
    );
INSERT INTO dbo.all_tickers WITH (TABLOCKX)(
  ticker_symbol,
  [Date],
  [Open],
  High,
  Low,
  [close],
  Volume
) 
SELECT
  ''' + ticker + N''',
  [Date],
  [Open],
  High,
  Low,
  [close],
  Volume
FROM #ticker_staging;'
FROM dbo.SCRIP
FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value('.',N'nvarchar(MAX)');
EXECUTE sp_executesql @SQL;
```

I am having problem in dealing with the `WITH` clause used in SQL Server to convert it into MySQL.

Since I am new to MySQL I think that's the major problem. If there are other problems in the code please suggest.

Comment: `MySQL` is not `SQL Server`. There are not the same

Comment: Read about MySQL's `LOAD DATA`